# Will this happen or is it a condition?

Tags: sentence-meaning, headlinese, future-time

I read current news on Wikipedia and one headline for August 31, 2016 said:

> Mother Teresa of Calcutta is to be canonized into sainthood after "proof" of two miracles.

For me it has two meanings. I know the first meaning is the correct one, but am I right to understand the second one? Here goes:

1) Recently there was a proof of 2 miracles and Mother Teresa is sure to be canonized.

2) Mother Teresa should be canonized, but it's required to have proof of two miracles (perhaps this condition is new).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means number 1,  because as of the date of the headline (August 31, 2016) two miracles had already been attributed  to her intercession. The second miracle was credited in December 2015, and  she will be canonized in two days, September 4, 2016.

However, if you had read this headline the day after she died, then it would have meaning 2, because at that point no miracles had yet been attributed to her intercession.

This is a problem with headlinese, which uses truncated language and often leaves out many forms of *to be*. In this case the phrase

> after "proof" of two miracles.

is ambiguous in the headline.

One basically has to know whether two miracles had already been officially attributed to her intercession or not before one can interpret the meaning of the headline.